# Razor DisplayFor will not display dates returned in JSON request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Controller:

```
public ActionResult HierarchyBinding_UnapprovedExpenseReportsAccounting([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {

        return Json(globalKip.DisplayUnapprovedExpenseReportsAccounting().ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Manager Approval Date")]        
public DateTime? EPR_DivManagerApprovalDate { get; set; }
```

Razor:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EPR_DivManagerApprovalDate)
```

All other HTML helpers display model data correctly. However dates do not appear at all. I have checked the returned data and the date is indeed being passed.

If I change DisplayFor to TextAreaFor, the correct date does appear, albeit in a different format than what the db is returning.

Anyone had similar trouble with getting dates to appear using DisplayFor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set your Action return type as JsonResult it will be more correctly

Comment: @C Sharper thx, give a link to rule next time like [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49597/which-one-is-correct-you-heard-it-correct-or-you-heard-it-correctly)

Comment: I'm confused. So you're trying to bind the View to the model, but you're sending back JSON, instead of a View and Model.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. ToDataSourceResult... isn't that a KendoUI function? in which case you'd be serializing a child of ActionResult into JSON which also wouldn't be of much use